# create a csv with the Items missing on the latest file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I am trying to create a csv with the Items missing on  the latest file log.
the comparing files are out.csv wish is a scan result, and the latest csv on the log folder.
the idea will be not repeating the rows already used before as the out.csv will have always the full content

```py
import os
import csv
import time 
import glob
 
list_of_files = glob.glob('./log/*.csv')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
previous_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
vurious = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I:%M:%S_%p")+".csv"
    
with open(latest_file, 'r') as t1, open('out.csv', 'r') as t2:
        fileone = t1.readlines()
        filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('./log/'+vurious, 'w') as mail:
        for line in filetwo:
            if line not in fileone:
                mail.write(line)
            else:
                print("nothing to email")
```

I have not a clue why it never  show a consistent result
I wonder if some one can help me with this
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using 'w' as mode, this overrides any previous content in the new file for every iteration.

Try the folowing solution, that writes all the rows at once:

```
with open('./log/'+vurious, 'w') as mail:
    l=[line for line in filetwo if line not in fileone]
    if len(l)==0:
        print("nothing to email")
    else:
        mail.writelines(l)
```